# Reverse proxy to access device with dynamic IP under NAT

Tags: proxy

I want to share (make public) some HTTP service on my laptop to access it from the internet. Laptop can be connected to the internet via different providers, e.g. via public Wi-Fi or 4G, so I can't be sure that my laptop can accept incoming TCP connections.

I'm thinking to set up some tiny reverse proxy with static IP address (e.g. using AWS EC2 t2.nano or t2.micro), and connect my laptop to this proxy. Then proxy will redirect all incoming requests from clients to my laptop:

```
1 - connect laptop to proxy
                 example.com
+--------+        +-------+
| laptop | -----> | proxy |
+--------+        +-------+

2 - all requests from clients will be redirected
 to connected laptop
                 example.com
+--------+        +-------+        +--------+
| laptop | <----- | proxy | <----- | client |
+--------+        +-------+        +--------+
```

I'm not sure it may be called, but is it a known practice
to do so? If yes does some software exist like proxy server and
connection tool?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network. Also product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic, except on [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

You only require a reverse proxy if the destination is to be selected based on application-layer information. E.g. you can use a reverse proxy to make multiple HTTP servers accessible through a single (public) TCP port; the proxy then forwards to the actual server based on the ''host'' tag. Of course, you can make the proxy accessible from the Internet using reverse NAT.

In your case, all you need is destination NAT aka port mapping aka reverse NAT. If the router's public IP changes, you can use a dynamic DNS service that gets updated each time the IP changes.

Alternatively, you could destination NAT from a publicly available server with static IP to the current public router's IP (also requires source NAT for the reply to get routed backwards) and then destination NAT again from the router's IP to the private IP of the actual server. For this you could also use a proxy which somewhat works like DNAT and SNAT combined.